# SQLite: How to update order data in table?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update a table to change the order of the data so it's ordered by some_column DESC.

I can do this by Selecting * and ordering by some_column DESC, and then inputting the data into a new table, but that's alot of hassle, so I'm wondering if there is another solution?

So what I want is to change this:

```
name|cost
John|50
Pete|75
Dojo|60
Neal|100
```

to

```
name|cost
Neal|100
Pete|75
Dojo|60
John|50
```

using the update statement. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no actual order of data in a database.  That is the point of `ORDER BY`.  It is pointless to try and store data in a specific order because you will need to update it each time your data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on the way data is physically stored in the SQL table. The best you can do is create a `VIEW` on that table which is ordered the way you want it to be, and use that in your subsequent queries:

```
CREATE VIEW ordered_view AS
SELECT name, cost
FROM mytable
ORDER BY cost DESC;

SELECT name, cost FROM ordered_view;
```

Comment: I'm going to pick this as the answer, I can't quite use it as I would have wanted to but I understand it better and I might be able to use the View function in the future. Thanks!